# Comment formatting

Tags: discussion, comments, formatting

I noticed that newlines are not allowed in the comments. I find that in many cases (esp questions involving code) newlines would be nice. Does anyone feel this way? If yes will the site templates allow it?

Comment: There's a related question here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5083/is-it-possible-to-generate-line-breaks-in-comments

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but this may be deliberate to keep the abuse of comments to a minimum.  They are supposed to be *comments*, not answers.  If you are showing code in a response, then it's a strong clue it should be a answer instead of a comment.

Comments are already abused.  Allowing pretty formatting would only invite more abuse.  Pretty formatting shouldn't be allowed for the same reason the maximum comment length shouldn't be extended either.